# CSS Help Floating a div to center when enough space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a div in the web browser when there is enough space. If not it should be collapsed between 2 divs.

This is the collapsed view

[image]

And this would be the expanded view
[image]

I've tried so many different things but nothing seems to work right. When I get something that looks right, the `filterDiv` ends up going over the top of `titleDiv` or `buttonDiv` or both.

Here's some code that I started with and should represent the collapsed view when the browser isn't very wide.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .controlsDiv{
        background-color:yellow;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .titleDiv{
        background-color:Red;
        width:25em;
        height: 5em;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .filterDiv {
        background-color: gainsboro;
        width: 600px;
        height: 10em;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .buttonDiv{
        width:25em;
        height:5em;
        background-color:green;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>

<div  class="controlsDiv" >
     <div class="titleDiv">
        <h2>titleDiv</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="filterDiv">
        <h2>filterDiv</h2>
        <h2>Centered in Browser Window</h2>
        <h2>titleDiv and ButtonDiv Collapsed</h2>
     </div>
     <div style:clear:both></div>
     <div class="buttonDiv">
        <h2>buttonDiv</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would suggest Media Queries ..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thanks for the reference Zak! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always position absolute required div:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .controlsDiv{
        background-color:yellow;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .titleDiv{
        background-color:Red;
        width:25em;
        height: 5em;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .filterDiv {
        background-color: gainsboro;
        width: 600px;
        height: 10em;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    @media(min-width: 900px) {
        .filterDiv {
        position: absolute;
        left: calc(50% - 300px);
        top: 0;
     }
    }
    .buttonDiv{
        width:25em;
        height:5em;
        background-color:green;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Wow! I guess I shouldn't be so stubborn all the time and kill myself trying to figure it out on my own. Two things I learned here, Media Queries and Calc. I have seen both of these used in other peoples code but never paid much attention and I had never really had a use for them until now. But now that I know how this works, I can see me using it a lot more! Thanks a bunch!!!